# Contour integral by parts: convergent becomes divergent

Tags: contour-integration

Please kindly take some time to read this long question.

Suppose I have a meromorphic function $f$.

Let $\gamma$ be a rectifiable closed curve. Suppose $f$ and $\ln(z-s)$ are continuous on $\gamma$. ($s$ is a constant.) $\gamma$ contains some poles.

Consider the integral $I$
$$I=\oint_\gamma f(z)\ln(z-s)dz$$

Clearly $I$ converges.

---

**Integration by parts for contour integral is $$\oint_\gamma f’(z)g(z)dz=-\oint_\gamma f(z)g’(z)dz$$**

---

$$I=\oint (z-s)’f(z)\ln(z-s)dz=-\oint (z-s)f’(z)\ln(z-s)dz-\oint(z-s)f(z)\frac1{z-s}dz$$ due to integration by parts.

Perform integration by parts again on the first integral,
$$I=-\oint f(z)dz+\oint\frac{(z-s)^2}2f’(z)\frac{dz}{z-s}+\oint \frac{(z-s)^2}2 f’’(z)\ln(z-s)dz$$

By repeated integration by parts,
$$I=\sum^N_{k=0}\oint\frac{(-1)^{k+1}f^{(k)}(z)(z-s)^k}{(k+1)!}dz+(-1)^{N+1}\oint \frac{(z-s)^{N+1}f^{(N+1)}(z)\ln(z-s)}{(N+1)!}dz$$

---

But, again, by integration by parts,
$$\oint f^{(k)}(z)(z-s)^kdz =(-1)^kk!\oint f(z)dz$$

---

So we have 
$$I=-\sum^N_{k=0}\frac1{k+1}\oint f(z)dz+ (-1)^{N+1}\oint \frac{(z-s)^{N+1}f^{(N+1)}(z)\ln(z-s)}{(N+1)!}dz $$

As you can see, as $N\to\infty$, the integral with logarithm tend to zero but the first term diverges as harmonic series.

---

Thank you for reading this long question completely. What’s the problem? Why does the convergent integral becomes divergent?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I didn't check all your transformations -- but why do you think that the integral with the logarithm tends to zero?

Comment: @joriki Because of the $(N+1)!$ in the denominator.

Comment: But it has $(z-s)^{N+1}f^{(N+1)}(z)$ in the numerator. How do you know that that doesn't grow as fast as $(N+1)!$?

Comment: @joriki Isn’t the derivatives of holomorphic function bounded on a rectifiable path?

Comment: They might be bounded, but that doesn't prevent them from growing with $N$?